# django-allauth running in SSL

Tags: django, ssl, https, django-allauth, django-sslify

I am able to setup django-allauth with social login using [this tutorial](http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/). 
However I need running all my website in https.

Can django-allauth be successfully and reliably used with django-sslify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web server you're hosting Django in handles SSL. If you put Nginx or Apache in front, for example, they will do all the SSL work. Django won't have any concept of being HTTP vs HTTPS.

The django-sslify module doesn't make a site run in SSL, it just redirects any detected non-SSL request to the equivalent SSL URL.

For django-allauth to work with SSL, all you need to do is ensure the configuration of redirect URLs is set to https://... etc.

Comment: Yes, I hosted django-allauth on apache with SSL and it worked.